# How does a "bulk connected to input voltage" mos work?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, nmos, pmos

[image]

This is the circuit I am supposed to analyze, but I don't understand at transistor level, what does a MOS do when its gate is grounded and its bulk is the input terminal! I mean bulk is tied to Vdd or GND for latchup problems, but when it is connected to Vin, it means it is positive in half period and negative in the other half period of ac voltage Vin...
and if you have a simpler circuit that helps to understand the such an implementation, please share.

Comment: Hint: another word for the bulk connection is "back-gate".

Comment: Try read this (page 23) https://books.google.pl/books?id=rlDrI05XAXsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bulk++input&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTncqVporSAhWmDZoKHZfHCTkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=bulk%20%20input&f=false

Answer (score 2):

By varying the BULK voltage, the gate-channel voltage is changed and the density of carriers in the channel.....is changed, which changes the channel resistance and alters the currents flowing left-right in the differential pair.